# copyFromLocal - extra/empty files getting copied to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I created two sample files -  'file1.txt' and 'file2.txt' in a folder on my local filesystem in Ubuntu and copied them to HDFS using the dfs command copyFromLocal.

On browsing the copied files thru NameNode UI, I can see two extra files (file1.txt~ & file2.txt~ each of 0 KB) being copied to HDFS though there was no other file in that folder except file1.txt and file2.txt

Below is the information from the NameNode UI -

```
Name          Type     Size

file1.txt     file     0.01 KB 

file1.txt~    file     0    KB

file2.txt     file     0.01 KB

file2.txt~    file     0    KB
```

Any suggestion/idea why these two extra files got created and how to fix this?

Comment: are your file1 and file 2 of correct size? if not then it means that hadoop is still trying to copy the files and has created temporaries.

Comment: Yes, they seem to be of correct size. I checked their properties and both are of size 15 bytes on disk.

Comment: Please add the exact command you used to copy

Comment: hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /home/user/Downloads/sample-input /user/hduser/input

Comment: try using hadoop fs because that what i use in my system. maybe there are some differences in the dfs and fs command